# Wordpress featured image request returning unknown

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I usually write in javascript, but I'm currently trying to set up a Wordpress theme for a side project.  I've found a few resources outlining how to use a set featured image as a div background image through inline styling, but they're a little old.  I'm currently trying a [basic method](https://www.minddevelopmentanddesign.com/blog/set-featured-image-background-image-wordpress/) I found, and have tried updating it to match the current [Wordpress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/), but I'm new to PhP.

In my functions file I have:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

In my template file I have:

```
<?php $bgImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large'); ?>

<section style="background: url('<?php echo $bgImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">

</section>
```

The section is rendering but the dev tools show "background: url((unknown))"

1. Could someone point a poor javascript-er in the right direction with the php here?
2. If someone is more familiar with wordpress, can they confirm for me that 'large' is a default image size, or do I need to register it?

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar approach:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

<div class="image row" style="background: url('<? echo $thumb_url;  ?>'); ">content</div
```

**Edit:**
Here is a list of image sizes by default.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes

Comment: That returns a link, instead of "unknown" but it directs to 
"*/wp-includes/images/media/default.png" which is an empty image.

Comment: :facepalm: Wrong post, the one rendering didn't have an image set to featured.  This solution works.

Comment: Good deal.  You can mark my solution as correct if it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead of yours.

```
<?php 
$featuredImg = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');
if($featuredImg) {
    $bgImg = $featuredImg;
} else {
    $bgImg = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default_bg.jpg';
}
?>
<section style="background: url('<?php echo $bgImg; ?>') no-repeat;">
</section>
```